# How to hide quoted text in Lion Mail?

Tags: macos, email

In Mail's conversation view, by default, quoted text is hidden and can be shown by clicking "See More from XXX" in the bottom of each message. After clicking that, how can quoted text be hidden again?

Answer (score 0):

From the list of mails, change the mail and come back to the previous one. It automatically folds all the quotes when you revisit it.

Answer (score -1):

Go to 'adjust (customize?) toolbar". Drag the "conversations" icon into your toolbar. Now you can click on that icon to hide or show all quoted text again.

Comment: That's not what they're asking. That hides and shows conversation threads, whereas they want so suppress the quoted text at will